# BPEL XPath expression tns or ns, what are these and when use them?

Tags: xpath, expression, bpel, ode

I noticed in XPAth Expresion we use `tns` and `ns2`. For example:

```
$input.playload/**ns2**:param
```

and

```
$input.playload/**tns**:param
```

What is the difference?

Comment: There may be no difference... It depends on the namespace your prefixes **ns2** or **tns** are respectively bound. Can you show us the `xmlns:tns` and `xmlns:ns2` definitions?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that too, I'm a newbie but it looks like the prefix tns is used for the variables of the process while ns is given (it can be another prefix) for XMLSchema's namespace (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema) so the variable types (int, string, ..etc) use the prefix ns